# LocalDate to GregorianCalendar conversion

Tags: java

I am trying to convert LocalDate to GregorianCalendar but GregorianCalendar output is giving me date which is one day before compare to LocalDate.

Below is the code snippet:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.of("Australia/Victoria")).withDayOfMonth(16).withMonth(10).withYear(2017);
        final GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.of("Australia/Victoria")));
        System.out.println(format.format(gregorianCalendar.getTime())); //prints 2017-10-15
    }
}
```

Issue comes when code runs on machine which has timezone other than "Australia/Victoria".
Can anyone please help me to point out what wrong I am doing?

Comment: Avoid mixing terrible legacy date-time classes with modern *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

You are mixing terrible legacy classes with modern *java.time* classes. **Don’t do that.**

```
LocalDate
.parse( "2017-10-16" )
.atStartOfDay(
    ZoneId.of( "Australia/Victoria" )
)
```

If you must use the terrible `GregorianCalendar` class, use the new conversion method added to the old class.

```
GregorianCalendar  // Terrible legacy class. Use only if you *must*. 
.from(
    LocalDate
    .parse( "2017-10-16" )
    .atStartOfDay(
        ZoneId.of( "Australia/Victoria" )
    )
)
```

## Details

Your code is a strange mish-mash of the terrible legacy date-time classes ( `SimpleDateFormat`, `GregorianCalendar` ) with the modern *java.time* classes that supplanted them ( `LocalDate` ).

Specifically, `ZonedDateTime` replaced `GregorianCalendar`.

A `LocalDate` represents only a date, without time-of-day and without time zone. In contrast, a `ZonedDateTime` (and `GregorianCalendar`) represents a moment: a date, a time-of-day, and a time zone.

Start with a `LocalDate`.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2017-10-16" ) ;
```

Specify a time-of-day.

```
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 15 , 30 ) ;  // 3:30 PM.
```

Specify the time zone you have in mind.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Australia/Victoria" ) ;
```

Combine to get a `ZonedDateTime`, a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
```

Or perhaps you want to use the first moment of the day as the time-of-day component. Do *not* hard-code this as 00:00:00. Some dates in some zones start at another time such as 01:00:00. Let *java.time* determine the first moment.

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ld.atStartOfDay( z ) ;  // Determine the first moment of the day on that date in that zone.
```

See that same moment in UTC. Extract a `Instant`, which is always in UTC.

```
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;
```

Notice that *all* of the above code comes from the *java.time* package family of classes.

Avoid `GregorianCalendar` wherever possible. But if you must interoperate with old code not yet updated to *java.time*, convert. Look to new `to…`/`from…` conversion methods added to *old* classes. In this case, see [`GregorianCalendar.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#from(java.time.ZonedDateTime)).

```
GregorianCalendar gc = GregorianCalendar.from( zdt ) ;
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy.]

Answer (score 2):

Set `TimeZone` to `SimpleDateFormat` like

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] arg){
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("Australia/Victoria");
        format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone(zoneId));
        final LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now(zoneId).withDayOfMonth(16).withMonth(10).withYear(2017);
        final GregorianCalendar gregorianCalendar = GregorianCalendar.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(zoneId));
        System.out.println(format.format(gregorianCalendar.getTime())); //prints 2017-10-16
    }
}
```

Comment: You are mixing terrible old legacy classes with modern *java.time* classes. Not a good idea.